# Change search results product url to include category

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How could I change my magento quick search products results url to include categories?

url.com/product.html to url.com/category/product.html

I know there is options for Canonical URL. ButI still would like to change it.

My products are single category, but a fail safe if it has more to choose the first one will be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

In the admin, go to

> System>Configuration>Catalog>Search Engine Optimizations

and set Use Categories Path for Product URLs

Or in search page,

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$category_id = $product->getCategoryIds();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id[0]);
$url = $product->getUrlPath($category);
```

Comment: it's already "Yes" by default. The problem it only works if you go by categories. But if you search for products it's always website.com/product.html

Comment: catalog/product/list.phtml. But this file is used for other product collection also. You may need to create different another phtml file for search results only